# Grep command to find same number digits

Tags: regex, bash, grep

What i am looking for is to find a grep command to find same number digits in a 4 digit sequence.

For example

```
1111  
1234  
5678  
1231  
2233  
4546
```

output should be

```
1111  
1231  
2233  
4546
```

Ive tried `grep "\([0-9]\)\\1"` but that doesnt catch numbers like 1231 or 4546
thanks

Comment: All of your sample input has the first digit repeated. Could it ever be the 2nd or 3rd digit, e.g. `1232` or `1233`?

Comment: any repeating digit in the 4 digit string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep '\([0-9]\).*\1' file
1111
1231
2233
4546
```

Match interger character in any position in the first cature group within the parenthesis. If the number captured is found again as a last occurance with the back reference `\1`, then a match is made.

[Back-References And Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html#:~:text=Back-references%20and%20Subexpressions%20%28GNU%20Grep%203.7%29%20The%20back-reference,example%2C%20%E2%80%98%20%28a%291%20%E2%80%99%20matches%20%E2%80%98%20aa%20%E2%80%99.?msclkid=e0c4d812cf6611ec9284618fff788c53)

Comment: Can you give some explanation what this syntax means and if there is any documentation about this?

Comment: Sure @Dominique Please check edit